# Shift a figure element more to the left corner

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

How can I put the image more to the left page side to have more space for it?

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{timetable}
\caption{Zeitplan}
\label{fig:timetable}
\end{figure}
```

thanks for your answer

Comment: Try `\centerline{}` around `\includegraphics` and remove `\centering`

Comment: If I set the width=1.5\textwidth then the image is no longer centered on the page. But I want to have it centered.

Comment: Did you try `\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}` as suggested in my previous comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have it automatically centered the way you intend, a possible approach is to use the makebox command:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{timetable}}
\caption{using SE saves time}
\label{fig:timetable}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `\xput[<horiz-fract>]{<contents>}` will put the center of `<contents>` at the fraction of the horizontal position. You can therefore shift the center of the graphics to the position you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\xput[2][0.5]{%
    \rule{#1\linewidth}{0pt}\makebox[0pt][c]{#2}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     \xput[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=1.25\linewidth]{timetable}}
     \caption{Zeitplan}
     \label{fig:timetable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\centerline` and let LaTeX center the figure :-), even if it is larger than `\textsize`  (It will protrude both margins the same amount)

Comment: @JLDiaz: You did not read my answer :-( It also gives you the option to move the centre of the figure left or right (that was part of the question). This is useful if you want to hang it out into the outer margins or if you want to center the title of a graph, etc.

Comment: I did read your answer (and gave it +1), but since the OP stated (in a comment) that he wanted the figure centered, I considered worthwhile to insist in the (much ignored) `centerline` solution

Comment: Fantastic answer, Mr. Danie.